# Can't see my TODOs in VIsual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, todo

I can't see any of my TODOs in Visual Studio Community 2015.

Here's a screenshot showing the issue:
[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion to what could be wrong?
[Other sites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txtwdysk.aspx) mention, that there should be a drop-down menu with a `Comments`, `User Tasks`, and `Comments`, but I can't see it.

Comment: Did you tried `ctrl +w,T`

Comment: I did,@Webruster - that shows the window...

And now it shows my TODOs. [Wat?](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/6a/22/ec/6a22ec1372350bb64757502d070d8492.jpg)

I will close this - thanks, @Webruster.

Comment: if it helped you please accept it as answer might be helpful for users using VS2015

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ctrl +w,T` to get the TODOs in VIsual Studio Community 2015

Comment: It is the answer, but ``Ctrl + W, T`` just displays the ``Task List`` window, as shown in the description. I think the real answer is to be found in the one of the todos being updated, triggering the search function of the ``Task List`` window.

Answer (score 0):

As @Webruster said, try `Ctrl W + T` (which just opens the window for `Task List`), which I had tried a few times. But now it works.

[image]

Solution might be, that I needed to update some of the comments, before VS would activate them.
But as can be seen on the figure, I still don't have the drop-down menu. 
But it shows my `TODO`-list.