# VS 2015: Tasklist doesn't list "TODO" comments (C++)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, comments, todo, tasklist

Althought the option in

```
Tools Menu -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> View -> Enumerate Comment Tasks
```

is set to **True**,

```
// TODO:...
```

isn't shown in the Tasklist Window.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you came right, but I found this, which worked for some people, perhaps it will for you as well.
[Can't see my TODOs in VIsual Studio Community 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118860/cant-see-my-todos-in-visual-studio-community-2015)

However, I seem to have a more serious problem. I also checked my Enumerate Comment Tasks setting and checked that TODO is listed in the `Options > Environment > Task List`, but my TODO doesn't even turn blue, the entire comment stays green.  For me `ctrl-W,T` as suggested in the post above also does something completely unrelated to opening the Task List (`ctrl-/,T` works for that, but doesn't solve anything, just opens the task list).

Perhaps, if you're having or had the same problem, you could share some insight? I don't want to repost the question.